# Sprites are disappearing when I zoom in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, zooming, unity3d-2dtools

In the scene view when I zoom in past a certain point all the sprites (apart from one) disappear and it makes it near impossible for me to edit them because they become too small to see clearly.

This only just started happening everything was fine before and I don't think I have really changed anything that could have affected their ability to show when zoomed in.

Comment: If you're working in a 3D space. Your Camera is most probably not using the Orthographic view. Now the UI's are either on 3d world space of your game which your camera can go over and make them invisible check all of your other sprites if their z position is the same with the other sprite that is having problem.

Comment: Although I am working in 2D and use the Orthographic view. However, you are right about the z position once I set the sprites z positions to that of the one showing they appear too. Thank you!

Comment: When this happens, go into 3d view, move the editor's camera backward (hold right mouse button, then hold the s key) away from your sprites and then return to 2d view. Now you can zoom in really far. The reason is because, for some reason, when you zoom in while in 2D mode, the editor's camera moves forward along the z axis. Eventually, the camera moves so far forward that the sprites are now behind the camera's near clip plane. I don't know why they move the camera forward while in 2d mode.

Comment: I see what you mean I have had to do this twice now, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z positions have to be same as that of the canvas I am using

Answer (score 3):

Press the F key a couple of times after selecting the sprite... it's for focus or something after you see it focus ...you will be able to zoom in endlessly to edit this is for sure a bug....I tried restarting unity first..then I tried adjusting the clipping low rate on the camera that is usually 0.3 to pure 0...and that was not it... the F key always gets it done I don't know why...also I changed the cameras near clipping plane back to 0.3 because it was not the issue.